# Sporadic slow network connection with Debian Jessie

Tags: web-services

My small Server with an i7 6700K Processor and 32Gb of RAM, running Apache 2.4.25 has some weird connection problems. It seems to depend either on connecting via IPv4/IPv6 or on the location of the user. When I try to connect from a friends house in cologne(net cologne), I randomly get disconnected in intervals of about 5 minutes. 
I asked another friend, who is currently in Spain if he could try reproduce the error. Strangely enough he gets the full download speed of 1.2MB/s and no disconnects. So maybe it also depends on the location or individual network provider use different ways to send packages of which some interfere with the network card drivers.

Comment: I believe you forgot to actually ask a question.

Comment: How long has the problem been going on?  If it has just been a day or two, it could still just be a network problem in the cologne area (ISP).  I'd be hesitant to say it's a server problem for sure if your friend in Spain has no issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the Kernel Mainline 3.16 which were only with 4.4 in this patch: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=eb9fae328faff9807a4ab5c1834b19f34dd155d4
This can result in a connection drop in TCP after a spike or lock your connection speed to a constant slow value when special TCP/IP Headers are used. This could explain why your friend from Spain can get a fast connection although your connection is unstable.
This causes an error with fastrecovery in combination with the Intel Skylake series.

There is currently no fix other than updating your kernel, however it is not recommended to do so.
Do you need to use Debian Jessie ? You could try out other distributions like archlinux or use a Windows Server build.
They seem to have a good support for current intel CPU's and Network cards. But use at-least a Windows Server 2012 for best results.